# Parsing an XML file ( forest of binary trees ) in C/ C++

Tags: c++, c, xml, xml-parsing

I'd like to parse a medium to large XML file on 64-bit Linux with C/ C++. What is the easiest way to write such a code?
The details about the XML are contained in this question [Working with a forest of binary trees stored in a large XML file (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223415/working-with-a-forest-of-binary-trees-stored-in-a-large-xml-file-php)

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". Pick one.

Comment: Do you want a theoretical "best practice" answer? Because this sounds like you're asking for a library, which would be off-topic.

Comment: You start by finding a library that does it for you. Trust me, writing a parser for XML (unless the XML data you want to parse is very small and very basic) is not something one does in a day or two, or even a *week* or two.

Comment: @user657267: It might be a theoretical answer.

Comment: @user965748 You might want to change the question then, "most convenient" is very subjective.

Comment: @user657267: changed to: easiest way to write such a code

Comment: Small, fast and easy to use: [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/). Its not 'feature complete' though.

Comment: boost's property tree can handle xml files. It's not "complete" - the xml must be structured like a tree, no back-referencing or things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libxml, the Gnome XML library, provides a fairly simple, but full-featured XML parser.

http://www.xmlsoft.org/

It's mostly a C library, and although there is a C++ facade for it, I often found it easier to write my own, light, wrapper around it's C interface. Since Gnome uses it, libxml is included in all Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost library header` by `#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>`. So you should install `boost`, and then link it. For more details about its usage, you can see [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.xml_parser_hpp). I hope this can help you.