# Boost XML parser RAM consumption

Tags: xml, boost, xml-parsing, boost-propertytree

I decided to check memory usage of PropertyTree for XML parsing with this piece of code. The XML has something over 120M, but this program was consuming over 2G when I decided to kill it. Is this standard consumption of PropertyTree or there is something wrong?

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using boost::property_tree::ptree;
  ptree pt;
  read_xml("c.xml",pt);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample XML? (Without further ado: I'd guess it's normal. Boost Property Tree is **not an XML library**. It's a **property tree** library. This means it will be "good enough" for config-file like applications)

Comment: The sample is shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223415/working-with-a-forest-of-binary-trees-stored-in-a-large-xml-file-php

Comment: That's not 120MB of XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your exact snippet compiled with Gcc 4.8 on 64-bit linux, and using the [117MiB input xml here](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/q32153366/input.xml.xz), I get peak memory usage of 2.1 GiB:

[image]

The whole thing executes in ~4-14s depending on optimization flags. Using tcmalloc we get 2.7s even.

You can see that at least 50% of the memory is directly in the `ptree` containers. In your PHP question you (correcly) mentioned that reading it all into a single DOM is just not such a great idea.

Even so, if you use [a more appropriate/capable library, like **PugiXML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387612/85371), the execution is over 10x as fast and the memory usage is roughly 1/6th:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
#include <pugixml.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file("input.xml");
}
```

Imagine what happens if you optimize for memory usage  by using a streaming API.

Comment: That's right, when I tried RapidXML, I got around 3.7 x size, with PugiXML it was 2.75x. Boost isn't really appropriate for XML parsing.